# Method cannot get updated value from a varible

Tags: java, multithreading, methods

I am trying to count number of words from three text files respectively. Three classes are running in multi-threads. In each thread, sum of the counted words will be passed to a class counter and update to sum all counts to the counter after all threads are completed.

I meet two problem that the "totalWordCount" can be updated by the class setter. But it cannot be gotten by a getter in the same class. Other problem is that I cannot check the Readfiles threads alive.

I have searched on internet & shoot many times but cannot solve, any comment are welcome, thanks a lot!

NumberWords class:
        public class NumberWords {
     private int activeThread;
     private int totalWordCount;
     private String getThreadName;

```
 public NumberWords(int activeThread) {
  this.activeThread = activeThread;
 }

 public synchronized void incTotalWordCount(int n) {
  totalWordCount += n;
  System.out.println("The total word count is " + totalWordCount);
 }

 public synchronized void printCount() {
  System.out.println("The total word count(print count) is " + totalWordCount);
 }

 public synchronized void decActiveThread() {
  getThreadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
  System.out.println(getThreadName);

  if (Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet().size() != 0) {
   // Get number of active threads
   activeThread = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet().size();

   activeThread--;
   if (activeThread == 0) {
    System.out.println("The total number of word in the three files is " + totalWordCount);
    System.out.println("The active threads is/are " + activeThread);
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Read file and count number of words:

```
    import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ReadFile1 extends Thread implements Runnable {
 private NumberWords nw;
 public ReadFile1(NumberWords nw) {
  this.nw = nw;
 }

 //set file path
 String path1 = System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "text1.txt";
 BufferedReader br1 = null;

 public void run() {
  try {
   br1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path1));

   String contentLine = br1.readLine();

   while (contentLine != null) {

    // Count number of words
    String[] parts = contentLine.split(" ");
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
     count++;
    }
    // Check number of words counted.
    System.out.println("The number of words in file(text1.txt) is " + count);

    //Pass words count to sum
    nw.incTotalWordCount(count);
    contentLine = br1.readLine();
   }
  } catch (IOException ioe) {
   ioe.printStackTrace();
  } finally {
   try {
    if (br1 != null) {
     br1.close();
    }
   } catch (IOException ioe) {
    System.out.println("Error in closing the BufferedReader");
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Main class:

```
public class TestReadFile {
public static void main(String args[]){

NumberWords nw = new NumberWords(args.length);

Thread rf1 = new Thread(new ReadFile1(nw));   
Thread rf2 = new Thread(new ReadFile2(nw));
Thread rf3 = new Thread(new ReadFile3(nw));

    rf1.start();
    rf2.start();
    rf3.start();

    //Get total word cont
    nw.decActiveThread();

  }
}
```

Comment: These classes are not so well formatted. An IDE can handle that.
Unfortunately, they don't compile either. Moreover, two classes are missing: `ReadFile2` and `ReadFile3`. It!s still unclear to me what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the only different of ReadFile2 & 3 with ReadFile1 is to read different text files, except this point all are the same codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
    public class NumberWords {
    private int totalWordCount;
    private int activeThreads;


    public synchronized void incTotalWordCount(int n) {
        totalWordCount += n;
        activeThreads--;
        System.out.println("The total word count is " + totalWordCount);
    }

    public synchronized void printCount() {
        System.out.println("The total word count(print count) is " + totalWordCount);
    }

    public int getActiveThreads() {
        return activeThreads;
    }

    public void setActiveThreads(int activeThreads) {
        this.activeThreads = activeThreads;
    }
}
```

ReadFile:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.nio.file.Files;
    import java.nio.file.Path;

    public class ReadFile implements Runnable {
        private NumberWords nw;
        private Path filePath;

        public ReadFile(NumberWords nw, Path filePath) {
            this.nw = nw;
            this.filePath = filePath;
        }

        BufferedReader br1 = null;

        public void run() {
            try {
                int count = 0;
                for (String line : Files.readAllLines(filePath)) {
                    String[] parts = line.split(" ");
                    for (String w : parts) {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
                nw.incTotalWordCount(count);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Main:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {

        NumberWords nw = new NumberWords();

        ExecutorService execSvc = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

        new Thread(new ReadFile(nw, Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "text1.txt"))).start();
        new Thread(new ReadFile(nw, Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "text2.txt"))).start();
        new Thread(new ReadFile(nw, Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "text3.txt"))).start();
        nw.setActiveThreads(3);
        while (nw.getActiveThreads() > 0) {
            Thread.sleep(100);
            System.out.println("Waiting for Tasks to complete!");
        }
        nw.printCount();

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Ben, it's work great and many thanks. Also thanks for introduce Executor to the active threads, I will study it. On the other hand, would you mind explain why I can't get the totalWordCount in my original codes? Sorry that I don't understand, thanks again.

Comment: Hey @faifai , what do you mean? do you mean that your code prints out: the number of words is: ( words in line )? you should declare int count outside the while loop and move incTotalWordCount after the while loop.

Comment: Hi Ben, noted and understand now! Thanks for your great help! Fai